# Roland TD11KV Problem recording using a flash drive

Tags: electronic-drumset

So basically I've been trying to record myself playing drum using a USB flash drive and when I plug the flash drive on the td11 module it assums that the flash drive is actually there, but then when I plug the flash drive on my computer so I can hear what I record it sounds completely different from what I played...

Does anyone knows how to solve this?
I've red that this problem can be because i'm not using a flash drive from Roland but I dont know

Comment: Can you clarify the problem - is the recording incorrect? The drive is being recognised? You are recording audio or digitally? Could you upload a clip of the sound so we can hear the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Roland TD11 is an electronic drum set.   The USB stick has two purposes.  You can play an audio file from it, so that you can play drums along to an already recorded song.   Or you can record your drum playing as a MIDI file.
Now think what a MIDI file is.  It doesn't contain any sound.  It just has data of which pad you hit, how hard and in what rhythm.   Play it back through the drum set, you'll get the sounds you expect.   Play it on your computer, you'll get whatever sounds the computer has.

Answer (score 0):

The flash drive might be too large. Many older devices can't use flash drives larger than 8GB. Also, make sure there is enough space on the drive and that it is formatted in FAT32.